# Can I straighten a twisted wooden pergola post?

Tags: wood

My 4x6 middle post on my pergola has twisted at the top over the years.  It is sturdy and placed in the ground in concrete.  Is there a way to straighten the twisted post?

Comment: No, it's the natural fibers in the wood and even if you manage to straighten it it will naturally go back.

Comment: Yep. The post was made with green lumber when it was installed and it twisted as it dried. For something like that where it will show, you want to use kiln dried lumber because it is kiln dried before it is milled into the dimensional lumber that you buy. But that is more expensive because more of the log gets wasted in chipping it after it has twisted so that the product is straight. After the fact there is nothing you can do short of replacing it...

Comment: Take off the edges and convert them to round posts. It will hardly decrease the strength.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can't twist it back.

You could probably plane it to square without massively diminishing its strength.

You could clad it in some thinner material, but you'd probably want that for all the posts.